# mysql proper index for where and group

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, where-clause

i have table like this

```
tbl_reg_process
- id, bigint(20)
- x1, varchar(255) nullable
- x2, varchar(255) nullable
- x3, varchar(255) nullable
- date1, datetime, nullable
```

this is explain query :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT x1,COUNT(x1) FROM tbl_reg_process WHERE date1 >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00' AND x3='U' GROUP BY x1
```

and this is result (**INDEX NOT USED**), and i got super slow response

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl_reg_process | ref  | x3,date1      | status | 768     | const | 585521 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

the question is, what index i should create so i can use where condition including date1, x3, and x1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x1` and `x3` will be exact matches, and `date1` will usually be an inequality, the index should be on either `(x1, x3, date1)` or `(x3, x1, date1)`. The general idea is that the inequality in the WHERE clause should use the last column in the index.